# Accessing different sheet from current sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I did my own research on the web but I am not 100% sure if my idea is possible. So maybe one off you guys can give me a guaranteed answer.

Could I access a completely different sheet from my Account?

For example: I am working in the spreadsheet "Hello" but want to get data and write data into the "World" spreadsheet.

Is this even possible or not?

Thank for the help guys

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, I think that when the Spreadsheet of `a completely different sheet from my Accout` is shared with your account or publicly shared, you can access to the Spreadsheet. If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `IMPORTRANGE` built-in function. You can find the documentation [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en).

For example: `=IMPORTRANGE("INSTERT_ID", "SPECIFY_RANGE")`.

Just change the `INSTERT_ID` to the ID of the spreadsheet you are trying to import data from, and the `SPECIFY_RANGE` to the range you want to import.